# Can't tell when Ansible server is up

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook for creating [Linode](https://linode.com) servers.  The problem I'm having is that my playbook isn't able to determine when the new server is up.  I'm using Ansible 2.8.4.  My playbook is as follows:

```
---
hosts: 127.0.0.1
gather_facts: False

- name: create server
  linode_v4:
    label: "{{ host_name }}_{{ 100 | random }}"
    access_token: "{{ linode_api4_key }}"
    type: "{{ plan_1GB }}"
    region: "{{ region_us_central }}"
    image: "{{ image_debian_10 }}"
    root_pass: "{{ linode_root_password }}"
    authorized_keys: "{{ my_ssh_public_key }}"
    tags: "inventory.ini"
    state: present
  register: linode

- name: save new server's ip address to a fact
  set_fact: ip_addr={{ linode.instance.ipv4 }}
  tags: always

- debug:
    var: ip_addr

- name: wait until new server is up and listening on port 22
  wait_for:
    host: "{{ ip_addr }}"
    port: 22
    delay: 2
    timeout: 600
    state: started
    msg: "Server port is not listening"
  tags: always
```

I also tried it this way:

```
- name: wait until new server is up
  local_action:
    module: wait_for
    state: started
    host: "{{ ip_addr }}"
    port: 22
    delay: 1
    timeout: 100
```

I've tried doing it using a wait_for and also via local_action but neither one is working.  The playbook never returns from the wait for task.  I monitor my Linode dashboard as the playbook runs and I can see that that IP address I'm feeding to the task via "ip_addr" is correct and the dashboard also shows me when the server is up.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved a similar problem with timeouts by registering the result of the action and retrying until the result isn't failed. You can configure the delay between retries and the maximum number of retries:

Also, I noticed you werent including state in your play, that might be causing an issue.

```
- name: wait until new server is up and listening on port 22
  wait_for:
    host: mywebserver.com
    port: 22
    state: started         # Port should be open
    delay: 0               # No wait before first check (sec)
    timeout: 4             # Stop checking after timeout (sec)
  register: waitfor_result
  until: waitfor_result is not failed
  retries: 50
  delay: 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the task you showed didn't seem to work either as it never seemed to complete.  I did add "state" to my second example above (omitting it was my mistake) but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Can you show the output of whats occuring/not completing? For me when Ansible fails the task it outputs a message to the command prompt/jenkins output saying "retrying". Do you not see a retry message?  Also - if you run the commands in separate playbooks does the wait_for ever work? - ie, run the play to make the host, manually confirm it comes up, then run another playbook that has the waitfor command? Maybe it is just always failing for firewall reasons, etc... Can't tell w/o the output though.

Comment: There is no output to indicate that something went wrong.  All I see if the string shown in the name task and then nothing more.  There's something deeper going on here that I don't understand.  I'll have to run this with "-vvv" and look for clues.  Thank you for your follow-up.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why no output is showing. If you want to share the results of splitting up the plays feel free too. Otherwise, maybe you can just do another command (make a file, etc) instead of wait_for that will fail unless the server is up and use the register/until/retries play style until it succeeds. That would rule out any issues with wait_for... good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You might try this.

```
- name: Check if host is accessible
  wait_for: host=<host to check> port=80 timeout=3
  register: host_accessible
  failed_when: False

- include: next_task_you_want.yml
  when: host_accessible.state is defined and host_accessible.state == "started"
```